# How can I import "autosklearn" using pyodide?

Tags: javascript, python, cors, pypi, pyodide

I want to perform ML in the browser with "autosklearn" via Pyodide. I think Im supposed to load micropip and then use that to load autosklearn from PyPI. But Im getting a CORS error and not sure how Im supposed to go about this.  Pyodide and PyPI shouldn't have any CORS restrictions right?

Heres how Im loading the initial packages

```
pyodide = await loadPyodide({
    indexURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.18.1/full/',
  });
await pyodide.loadPackage(['scikit-learn', 'micropip']);
```

Heres the browser code

```
pyodide.runPython(
    `
      import micropip
      micropip.install('autosklearn')
      import autosklearn.classification
    `,
  );
```

And here is my error. Notice the CORS error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Autosklearn is not compatible with Pyodide. That package requires modules, such as requests, which cannot run in a browser due to browser sandbox security restrictions.

The CORS error in your screenshot is caused by a page not found (404) error.

There is no easy solution for importing **auto-sklearn**. That package would need to be modified to not use features that do not exist in a browser such as sockets.

Comment: Thank you, John. How come autosklearn works in Jupyter though? Wouldnt it need to behave the exact same way e.g. requesting the autosklearn package over the internet?

Comment: @Leon - Jupyter does not run in the browser. Only an interface runs in the browser. The work is done by a service (web server) that the browser connects to.

Comment: You can use typical Jupyter modules through MyBinder.org in your browser. Those have normal Python-backed kernels and run on temporary remote computers. Not in web assembly on your computer. For using some packages, you may need to use a configuration file to make sure it is installed via conda/mamba or pip in the image used to launch. A lot you can install after the sessions is already running. Pyodide,pyscript., and JupyterLite are all very experimental and developing fast.